# They use me... What am I?

Tags: riddle

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for others.

I'm used to getting hit,
but there's no alternative.

I die as fast,
as I rise again.

**What am I?**

Comment: is this a physical object which we can feel/fill into something, ?

Comment: @user2408578: Yes, it is a physical object!

Comment: @TobiasPeter is it raise or rise?

Comment: raise --> as _revive_

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a Java Exception?

Comment: Did you mean "I'm used to get hit" (i.e. people use me to make sure they are hit) or "I'm used to getting hit" (i.e. I get hit all the time and I've gotten used to it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are

> a cell phone

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

> It's a transmitter/receiver (complex) in a simple (easy) case. Smartphones have even less buttons.

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for the others.

> Some people have ringtones some put it on silent

I'm used to get hit,
but there's no alternative.

> People are always tapping on it to text

I die as fast,
as I raise again.

> It refers to the battery life. When it dies, you'll plug it and it raise again

Comment: Most phones don't drain as fast as they charge.

Answer (score 12):

Is it

> an alarm clock?

*I'm complex inside,

but easy on the outside.*

> It looks simple on the outside, just a clock (or a digital display), but inside are lots of complex clockwork or electronics.

*I'm loud for one,

but quiet for the others.*

> It's loud for you so that it wakes you up, but it shouldn't be too loud for anyone else.

*I'm used to get hit,

but there's no alternative.*

> The bells on a mechanical alarm clock are used to getting hit by a hammer or whatever - that's how it works.

*I die as fast,

as I raise again.*

> <s>You stop the clock from ringing each morning when you get up, but then set it again that evening to ring again the next morning.</s> If you set the clock to snooze alarm, it starts ringing again almost as quickly as you stop it (thanks to **user2408578** for this idea).

Comment: +1 Nice but last "I die as fast" not true with me.....even alarm rings i keep on SNOOZE and it wont die fast ;) may be that is better explanation :)

Comment: @user2408578 I agree the last verse is the weakest ... thought it was worth a try though.

Comment: yep.....how about SNOOZE alarm for last line...Suits better isn't it?

Comment: You're not too far away, but unfortunately it's wrong :/

Comment: ohh no now ill have to think again hehehe :D But this it fits all clues i guess.?

Answer (score 8):

My guess would be

> Revolution?

**Explanation line by line:**

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

> A revolution can have very complex grounds but also have a simple goal.

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for the others.

> Some revolutions start by doing something with a big group of people. Some just with one.

I'm used to get hit,
but there's no alternative.

> There is always resistance against a revolution, there has to be.

I die as fast,
as I raise again.

> Revolutions can die as quick as they start.

Comment: This is very innovative and creative, but wrong :(

I'm sorry :)

Upvote for creativity though!

Answer (score 6):

I would say the answer is:

> a keyboard (or keys on a keyboard)

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

> keyboards are composed of simple squares on the outside, but complex mechanical and electrical components on the inside

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for others.

> keyboards can be loud (mechanical) or quiet (silicone)

I'm used to get hit,
but there's no alternative.

> you HAVE to hit the keys on the keyboard in order to use it. There's no way around it.

I die as fast,
as I rise again.

> keys are depressed as fast as they spring back up

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> A faulty radio that needs percussive maintenance (ie: hitting the radio)?

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

> Most radios are quite simple on the outside, but can look like a rats nest inside.

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for the others.

> Volume of the radio. Some people also use headphones.

I'm used to get hit,
but there's no alternative.

> The percussive maintenance part. Somethings wrong with the radio and whoever is listening has no other way of fixing the radio but...

I die as fast,
as I raise again.

> ...percussive maintenance never really works for very long. Hitting the radio is only a quick fix.

Comment: Seems like a longshot.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a

> toilet flush.

I'm complex inside, but easy on the outside.

> Try to fix one you will understand

I'm loud for one, but quiet for the others.

> Loud for the one who flush, not that loud for the others

I'm used to get hit, but there's no alternative.

> this is what got me into in, normally there is no other alternative when you have to flush

I die as fast, as I raise again.

> Maybe some kind of metaphor about the fact that as long as the flush is finished, the 'button' is up again'

Answer (score 2):

it's

> heart
>  -complex inside but people just draw it ♥
>  -loud for you when you run or exercise you will hear beats, but no one will hear it
>  -it got hit when some one you love dies or you break up with GF (or BF)
>  -if you are religious then you know that after death there is another life

it's idiot answer i know :D

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. I edited to hide your answer with spoiler tags. Please look over the edit to see if anything needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I know the solution has been found, but here is another answer I thought of before reading the existing suggestions.

> I am polyurethane foam, or some other soft man-made foamed material like neoprene.

I'm complex inside, but easy on the outside.

> Try mathematically modelling a foam. The surface is frequently easy, because it is almost smooth (if the cells are closed on the surface), the porous media inside is very complex.

I'm loud for one, but quiet for others.

> Acoustic foam is used for making rooms quieter/reducing echoes within the room. But contrary to popular opinion, it does not soundproof the room, so that the neighbor still hears your bagpipe lessons.

I'm used to getting hit, but there's no alternative.

> These foams are used to buffer physical impacts. For example, the foam around the car door hole gets hit by the door every time it's closed.

I die as fast, as I rise again

> I admit the word "die" does not fit my solution so well. But these foams are very, very elastic. You can depress them, and once you remove the weight, they rise up again in seconds, getting to their previous height and shape.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple this answer is.

> The mind.

Why?

I'm complex inside,
but easy on the outside.

> People are always trying to understand you, what you think, who you are. It looks simple, but only you know your true self.

I'm loud for one,
but quiet for others.

> You may be quiet on the outside, but your mind is always speaking inside your head.

I'm used to get hit,
but there's no alternative.

> I'd call it "sadness". We just can't help it.

I die as fast,
as I rise again.

> You're always changing what you're thinking. Always thinking of different things.

That's what i think it is.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I thought it was

> an elevator..

I'm complex inside, but easy on the outside.

> There's many buttons inside an elevator, but there are only two buttons on the outside (up or down)

I'm loud for one, but quiet for the others.

> If there are more people than an elevator can accommodate, it will make *beep* sound, but if one people get out of there, it would be back to normal.

I'm used to get hit, but there's no alternative.

> People hit the buttons of floors.
>  (or stump on the elevator..?)

I die as fast, as I rise again.

> Elevators always go up and down.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I've added spoiler tags on your behalf; you can check the edit history to see what I did, so you know what to do next time.